# knockout - how to bind date only

Tags: date, datetime, knockout.js

I have an array, one key is createDate. In a foreach looping of the array, I pull the createDate value via a knockout text binding.

```
<span data-bind="text: createDate"></span>
```

The value displays: '2013-04-24T16:29:00.38' ... this is the way it exists in the database. Is there a way to format (within the binding) to show just the date only? Or do I have to save it as date only in the database to achieve this?

E.g., you can use the following to set 2 decimals:

```
<span data-bind="text: price.ToFixed(2)"></span>
```

Is there something simple such as this to only display: '2013-04-24'

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For me the key is [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

You can do something as simple as this:

```
<span data-bind="text: moment(createDate()).format('MM/DD/YYYY')"></span>
```

Or you could write a binding helper [like this guy does](http://www.binaryheap.com/2012/10/07/knockout-binding-for-date-formatting/), so it would be something like:

```
<span data-bind="dateString: createDate, datePattern: 'MM/DD/YYYY'"></span>
```

Comment: @ Jason: using moment.js works great with one minor correction: "text: moment(createDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY')" ... createDate is not a function so leave out the (). This is clean and easy, so I didn't even try the alternative with the binding helper. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Cool, glad it helped.  I was thinking the createDate was a ko.observable(), but if it isn't then yeah, no need for the '()'.

Comment: @JasonHaley the link to your second solution is dead :(

Comment: This link might work (different article probably, but demonstrates the same concept): http://blog.json.codes/web-development/binding-dates-using-knockout-moment-js/

Comment: How is this possible and where is it documented?

Comment: you can try this : http://www.aaronkjackson.com/2012/04/formatting-dates-with-knockoutjs/

Answer (score 0):

thanx it worked for me to display time only :

```
 <td data-bind="text:moment(OpeningTime()).format('h:mm:ss a')"></td>
```

Answer (score -2):

Add this javascript:

```
String.prototype.Format = function (fmt) {
var myDate = this;
var o = {
    "M+": myDate.getMonth() + 1,
    "d+": myDate.getDate(),
    "h+": myDate.getHours(),
    "m+": myDate.getMinutes(),
    "s+": myDate.getSeconds(),
    "q+": Math.floor((myDate.getMonth() + 3) / 3),
    "S": myDate.getMilliseconds()
};
if (/(y+)/.test(fmt)) fmt = fmt.replace(RegExp.$1, (myDate.getFullYear() + "").substr(4 - RegExp.$1.length));
for (var k in o)
    if (new RegExp("(" + k + ")").test(fmt)) fmt = fmt.replace(RegExp.$1, (RegExp.$1.length == 1) ? (o[k]) : (("00" + o[k]).substr(("" + o[k]).length)));
return fmt;
```

};

Then you can use like this:

```
<span data-bind="text: createDate().Format('MM/DD/YYYY')"></span>
```

Comment: @ Zack: thanks but moment.js works great and is easy (via answer above).